# TensorFlow Lite: How to change model output to list of image coordinates?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm able to run the TensorFlow lite image [classification example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) on my mobile device. However, I want to exchange the image classification model to a pose recognition model. In my case, the output should consist of a list of (x,y) coordinates.

The [respective line](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatMobileNet.java#L97) in the code looks like this:

```
  @Override
  protected void runInference() {
    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
  }
```

However the `tflite.run` function has no source code (only available as binary). So I don't know how it works or how to manipulate its return values.

I worked with TensorFlow before, however, I don't know how to create a TensorFlow model that is compatible with the input and output expected by TensorFlow Lite.

Can anyone help or point me to some more detailed tutorial than the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/android)?

Comment: The `labelProbArray` itself gets populated with the outputs fetched from the model after inferencing. Why do you need to modify the returns of the `tflite.run()` method?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the demo to work with a different model that has a different output modality (pose coordinates). So I need to change the output dimensions that tflite  is accepting

Comment: What kind of output do you need exactly?

Comment: I found a tool called `netron` to read out the exact output dimensions of the network. They are `[1, 23, 17, 17]`, which I would need to store in some multidimensional array for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion has to be done to the TF model before converting it to tflite. A pre-existing tflite model can be inspected using the tool "[netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)"

When using a self trained model (.ckpt files) one has to undergo the procedure of

- creating a graph definition file for evaluation
- use `freeze_graph` to freeze the previously created graph definition file using the latest .ckpt file from your training to assign it some weights
- using `tflite_convert` (eg from command line) to convert the frozen graph to a tflite file which you can push to your android application